# Cochains and Cocycles.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to prove that:

1. The cup product of two cocycles is a cocycle;
2. The cup product of a cocycle with a coboundary is a coboundary.

Here's my attempt:

1. Suppose $u$ and $v$ are cocycles, i.e. $\partial(u) = \partial(v) = 0$. Then by the Leibniz rule: 
   \begin{equation*}
   \partial(u \smile v) = \partial(u) \smile v + (-1)^{|u|} \ u \smile \partial (v) = 0
   \end{equation*}
   Since $\partial(u \smile v) = 0$ we have that $u \smile v$ is a cocycle.
2. Let $u$ be a cocycle and $v$ a coboundary. Then $\partial(u) = 0$ and $v = \partial(w)$. Then $\partial(w \smile u) = \partial(w) \smile u + (-1)^{|w|} \ w \smile \partial(u) = \partial(w) \smile u = v \smile u$. Therefore $v \smile u$ is a coboundary. Similarly, $\partial(u \smile w) = (-1)^{|u|} \ u \smile v = \pm u \smile v$.

I'm not quite sure if that $-u \smile v$ implies that $u \smile v$ is a coboundary.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: And what is the question? 

Comment: I was intrigued at how the expressions $(u \smile u)$ look like little smiles, and wondered what the Latex code was. To my great surprise, it was just that: `\smile`! :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but $\partial( u \smile v)$ should be zero, since it's a coboundary. Recall the cup product is graded commutative, so if $v \smile u$ is a coboundary then so is $u \smile v$.

Comment: Sorry, it's $\partial(u \smile w)$ not $v$. I read that the cup product is graded commutative but I didn't prove it, so I can't use this.

Comment: What are you trying to show? If your goal is to show $u \smile v$ is a coboundary without using commutativity just note that $\partial$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism, so $\partial (-u \smile w)=u \smile v$, if $\partial (u \smile w)=-u \smile v$. In general, you're trying to show that something is contained in the image of a group homomorphism. But the image of a homomorphism is always a group, and thus contains its inverses

Comment: $\partial(-u \smile w) = \partial(-u) \smile w + (-1)^{|-u|} \ -u \smile \partial(w)$. If $-u$ is a cocycle, then we have left $\pm -u \smile v$. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\partial(u \smile w) = - u \smile v$, then $\partial(-u \smile w) = u \smile v$.

Therefore the cup product of a cocycle and a coboundary, in either order, is a coboundary.